# jquery functions

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm trying to write my own function like with no luck. "...is not a function"

```
jQuery.fn.extend ({
myFirstFunction : function () { alert ("first function") }
});

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){           
              $.myFirstFunction();
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$.myFirstFunction = function () { alert ("first function") };

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){           
          $.myFirstFunction();
});
</script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Mdqw6/

Or

```
jQuery.fn.extend ({
  myFirstFunction : function () { alert ("first function") }
});

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){           
              $(element).myFirstFunction();
    });
</script>
```

Read more at http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring

Answer (score 3):

There is a difference between `$.extend()` and `$.fn.extend()`, depending on what you want to do and how you want to access your function:

```
$.fn.extend({
    myFunction: function(){...}
});
$('div').myFunction();

$.extend({
    myFunction2: function(){...}
});
$.myFunction2();
```

In your case, use `$.extend()` and it should work fine.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery.fn.nameOfFunction = function(){
      alert('nameOfFunctuin was called');
    }

    $().ready(function(){
      $('<div></div>').nameOfFunction()
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

If what you want to do is add a "global" jQuery facility, you probably want:

```
jQuery.extend({
  myFirstFunction : function () { alert ("first function") }
});
```

It's just "jQuery.extend", not "jQuery.fn.extend". You can also just write:

```
jQuery.myFirstFunction = function() {
  alert("hello world");
};
```

Using "extend()" is handy when you're adding a bunch of functions.